# disconnected ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

Is there a totaly ordered infinite set $A$ with the least element $a$ and the greatest element $b$ such that for any sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ and $\{\beta_n\}$ in $A$ which satisfies  $\alpha_n<\beta_n$, we can deduced that $\lim\alpha_n<\lim\beta_n$ (or even $\sup \alpha_n<\sup\beta_n$) ?( the last inequalities is remained strict)

Comment: If $\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\dots$ and $\beta_n=\alpha_{n+1}$ for all $n$, then $\lim\alpha_n=\sup\alpha_n=\sup\beta_n=\lim\beta_n$, so what you want is impossible if your set has an infinite increasing sequence. If it has an infinite decreasing sequence $\beta_0>\beta_1>\dots$ then, setting $\alpha_n=\beta_{n+1}$ we again get $\lim\alpha_n=\lim \beta_n$. So your set has to be finite.

Answer (score 2):

The total order $ \omega + \omega^*$ (that is, the order type of the natural numbers followed by the reverse of the order type of the natural numbers) is an example of such a total order.  The only sequences in this order that have a limit are eventually constant.

Comment: Is it possible to find $A$ such that $\sup\alpha_n<\sup\beta_n$?

Comment: If you require that suprema always exist, then Berci's counterexample works.  If you don't, then $\omega + \omega^*$ remains an example.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n$ is any sequence with $a':=\lim \alpha_n$ such that $\alpha_n< a'$ for all $n$, then set $\beta_n:=a'$ for a counterexample.

Comment: I want to hold the property for all sequences in $A$.